# Keep iphone active while running program

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to set iPhone device to stay active ( to not lock ) while my app is running ?
Any idea

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This code will prevent your iPhone from going to sleep while your app is running

```
// avoid sleeping when this application is running
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;
// Or simpler
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

Comment: Note to anyone reading this accepted answer: this will only work if you have an `application` object already, which isn't common. Instead, you should use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;`

Answer (score 78):

I'm not sure if this prevents the device from locking, but you can prevent the screen from dimming with the `UIApplication`'s [`idleTimerDisabled`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/idleTimerDisabled) property:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

From the documentation:

> **Important**: You should set this property only if necessary and should be sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists. Most applications should let the system turn off the screen when the idle timer elapses. This includes audio applications. With appropriate use of Audio Session Services, playback and recording proceed uninterrupted when the screen turns off. The only applications that should disable the idle timer are mapping applications, games, or similar programs with sporadic user interaction.

Answer (score 6):

If you landed here looking for an answer in Swift, it's this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

**for Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

[The warning in this comment still applies.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493522/5041820)

Comment: Swift 3: `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`