# How can I prevent that iPhone OS switches off the screen or goes into standby?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

How could I make sure that iPhone doesn't disable the screen or go to sleep for about 20 to 30 minutes?

Answer (score 4):

Check this link: [Keep iphone active while running program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493495/keep-iphone-active-while-running-program)

In short:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```